# Transparent PNG div not showing on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

Real simple, but I don't know what's going on...

I have a kenburns-ish slideshow in the background, over it I have a bgImageFramer.png transparent png to fade out the sides (which makes reading the navigation (1, 2, 3) much easier.

Page looks great in all major browsers on desktop... But neither Chrome or Safari on my iPad or iPhone will show the bgImageFramer...

Thanks for everybody's help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the kenburns.js plugin and how it layered it's own z-indexes.  I reset all of the z-indexes in the stack >0 and the layering is now correct.